# TimeSpan.ParseExact with Milliseconds

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

I am trying to parse a string into a timespan format of *minutes:seconds:milliseconds*. So `00:00:02` I would expect `2` milliseconds. But it is parsing as `20`.

```
const string tmp = "00:00:02";
var t1 = TimeSpan.Parse(tmp);

// minutes: seconds: milliseconds
var t2 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(tmp, @"m\:s\:ff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[image]

Why is milliseconds **20** and not **2**?

Comment: Because your fractional portion is 0.02. Which is 20 ms. If you want 2 ms, you need to input 0.002. That would actually be 2 ms. Just because _you_ decided to use `':'` as the decimal separator, that doesn't change how the fractional portion of the seconds are parsed. They are still a decimal fraction and follow decimal rules.

Comment: Use `00:00:002` as source string & parse it: `TimeSpan.ParseExact(tmp, @"m\:s\:fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. This will output 2 ms as expected, which requires 3 digits for fractional position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is milliseconds 20 and not 2?

Because `1 sec = 1000 ms` and not 60 like seconds or minutes so consequently it's `0.020 = 20/1000`, 2ms would be `0.002 = 2/1000`.

Comment: This makes sense now. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code a little. Below is the working code:

```
        const string tmp = "00:00:002";
        var t1 = TimeSpan.Parse(tmp);

        // minutes: seconds: milliseconds
        var t2 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(tmp, @"m\:s\:fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```